# Multi Line text field in Titanium 3 for bb10

Tags: javascript, titanium, blackberry-10

Is there any alternative to Ti.Ui.TextArea in Titanium using javascript.
I need a multi line text field, but since the titanium3 for bb10 is still in preview, it has not been implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

textField is for only single line input. you have to use textArea for multi line inputs but unfortunately there is no TextArea support till now for bb10. It will be added in p2 after p1 is implemented.

Comment: BUt TextArea is still not available in BB10 Titanium Sdk. https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_blackberry/blob/master/docs/ReleaseNotes.txt

Comment: they have plan to implement textArea  in p2,once p1 is implemented. look at line no 75 in your doc link.

Answer (score 0):

It's not planned to be implemented until P2 according to the release notes [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_blackberry/blob/master/docs/ReleaseNotes.txt)